# How to redirect wildcard subdomain with Cloudflare DNS and Lets' Encrypt SSL to HTTPS version?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, cloudflare, http-redirect, wildcard-subdomain

I have set up my Digital Ocean hosted website with Cloudflare DNS and would like to make https redirection to all subdomains, eg when the user looks for [http://]sub.exmple.com, to be automatically redirected to https://sub.exmple.com, as it nicely working for the website itself (exmple.com redirects to https://exmple.com)

My environment: Apache2 with Ubuntu 16.4 server, PHP7, MariaDB
I have set up the A record for wildcard redirection on both Cloudflare and my hosting provider to A | *.exmple.com | IP

[image]

As Cloudflare does not support wildcard SSL certificate, I have used the plugin that allows setup of free Let's Encrypt wildcard SSL with Cloudflare API.
I have tried with .htaccess instructions as well, however, it seems that Cloudflare settings override it.

```
# *** force https:// only if online
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

What am I doing wrong, and what are my options?
[image]

Comment: You need to contact cloudflare for this. Or dig more into cloudflare settings.

Comment: Well, I have asked them on their forum first, and they declared it as no Cloudflare related issue... instead, they pointed me out to look at the hosting/server settings.

Strange thing is that I can get SSL page without issues if I directly put https://subname.bookingsready.com to the address bar, I just can't get my .httaccess instructions to redirect  subname.bookingsready.com to the https:// version automatically as I explained in my original question... 

I can't distinguish if this is the .httaccess issue, or some other setting (eg server, DNS, or else) and that is my question?